# test react component that use query and subscription with apollo client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, apollo

Does anyone have a tip about testing react components that use query and subscriptions with apollo client? It seems like when you are using the `<MockedProvider />` component with `mocks` and `link` props it just ignores the mocks.
thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You should not be messing with the `link` prop of `MockedProvdier` unless you have a good reason to. The default link that is used in the `MockedProvider` is [MockLink](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/9049e65a9f8bc137573bf901fcb17032fbfbe962/src/utilities/testing/mocking/mockLink.ts#L39), which manages the logic that produces a mock for a given query. Model the example given in the [apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/) like so and it should work:

```
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import { GET_DOG_QUERY, Dog } from './dog';

const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: GET_DOG_QUERY,
      variables: {
        name: 'Buck',
      },
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        dog: { id: '1', name: 'Buck', breed: 'bulldog' },
      },
    },
  },
];

it('renders without error', () => {
  const component = TestRenderer.create(
    <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
      <Dog name="Buck" />
    </MockedProvider>,
  );

  const tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree.children).toContain('Loading...');
});
```